# Retrofit JSON OBJECT Post

Tags: android, json, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I want to send a json object to post request.

The Json have the next Structure:

```
{ "email:"test@test.com",
  "password": "test",
   "hash": "true"
}
```

This works nice in POSTMAN but I don't know how i have to define the key in retrofit like in POSTMAN.

[image]

At this moment, I Created a @Body like this:

```
public class LoginRequest {


private String email;
private String password;
private String gethash;

public LoginRequest(String email, String password, String hash) {
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.gethash = hash;
}
```

}

But I really don't know where i have to define the key.
Then, I am trying to call the POST request like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@Field("json")` instead of `@Body` in your endpoint definition:

```
@POST("/login")
public Observable<DataLogin> getLogin(@Field("json") LoginRequest loginRequest);
```

Also, you must use a converter to convert objects. Here's a sample for GSON. You'll essentially need to create a custom wrapper for the default `GsonConverterFactory` because it doesn't implement the `stringConverter(...)` method that converts values annotated with `@Field` and such to strings.

```
public class GsonStringConverterFactoryWrapper extends Converter.Factory {
    private GsonConverterFactory converterFactory;

    public static GsonStringConverterFactoryWrapper create() {
        return create(new Gson());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")
    public static GsonStringConverterFactoryWrapper create(Gson gson) {
        if (gson == null) throw new NullPointerException("gson == null");
        return new GsonStringConverterFactoryWrapper(gson);
    }

    private final Gson gson;

    private GsonStringConverterFactoryWrapper(Gson gson) {
        this.gson = gson;
        converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gson);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations,
                                                            Retrofit retrofit) {
        return converterFactory.responseBodyConverter(type, annotations, retrofit);
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type,
                                                          Annotation[] parameterAnnotations, Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return converterFactory.requestBodyConverter(type, parameterAnnotations, methodAnnotations, retrofit);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Converter<?, String> stringConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        return new GsonStringConverter<>(gson);
    }

    public static class GsonStringConverter<T> implements Converter<T, String> {
        private final Gson gson;

        GsonStringConverter(Gson gson) {
            this.gson = gson;
        }

        @Override
        public String convert(@NonNull T value) throws IOException {
            return gson.toJson(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, when you create the Retrofit instance, just use this adapter:

```
new Retrofit.Builder()
 .addConverterFactory(GsonStringConverterFactoryWrapper.create(gson)) // if you don't have a custom GSON instance, just call .create()
 // [...] other settings
 .build();
```

Comment: Now I Can execute but always return are can not authenticate, checkin it, it seems that my Object is null, but don't understand why.

Comment: I don't know what kind of converter factory you use, but it seems like `GsonConverterFactory` does not implement the `stringConverter`. I'll update the answer to create a new converter for GSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when I  arrive at home will try it.

Comment: So much thanks, I can find all my mistakes, and with your class all is worked now. Thanks for your patience too.

Answer (score 0):

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
public Observable<DataLogin> getLogin(@Field("json") String json);
```

Comment: Have it. I have another mistake. Only Works if I i did with a LoginRequest Object.
Thanks for the answer